# need regex to reject duplicates

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

My test string is:
**Named_Hires!$W$16:$W$87 + Calc_Named_HC!AD$32:AD$103 +A + Named_Hires!$W$16:$W$87**

my regex is **\w+(?=!)**

It is working correctly and extracts Named_Hire,  Calc_Named_H, and  Named_Hires

I want to eliminate duplicates so that the 2nd Named_Hires won't be extracted
TIA

Comment: make a set from the extracted values?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `\w+(?=!)` matches 1+ word chars asserting what is on the right is a `!`

If you want to assert that the whole pattern occurs only once, you could use a capturing group for `\w+` and wrap that group in another group adding the ! as well.

Then you could use a negative lookahead asserting that the whole group does occur once and get the word characters from the second group.

Your match is in the second capturing group.

```
((\w+)!)(?!.*\1)
||
|Group 2
|
Group 1
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group 1

  - `(\w+)` Capturing group 2, match 1+ word chars
  - `!` Match literally
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `.*\1` Match any char 0+ times followed by a backreference to group 1
- `)` Close negative lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y5u4IW/1)

Comment: That `(\w+)(?=!)(?!.*\1)` may filter out many more matches than expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, I have added the `!` to the match and used 2 groups.